# ROS MoveIt! move_group.launch

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i try to run, the original **move_group.launch** file, generated by **MoveIt!**, i get the following error:

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [25531]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to aea97446-1118-11e5-a1c4-14feb5ae1f20
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [25544]
started core service [/rosout]
process[move_group-2]: started with pid [25561]
[ERROR] [1434123343.429734522]: Robot model not loaded
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
what():  Character [_] is not valid as the first character in Graph Resource Name                    [_planning/shape_transform_cache_lookup_wait_time].  
Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, / and in some cases ~.
[move_group-2] process has died [pid 25561, exit code -6, cmd /home/***/moveit/devel/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group __name:=move_group __log:=/home/***/.ros/log/aea97446-1118-11e5-  a1c4-14feb5ae1f20/move_group-2.log].
log file: /home/***/.ros/log/aea97446-1118-11e5-a1c4-14feb5ae1f20/move_group-2*.log
```

Google has no idea, I have no idea what could be the problem:)

`<include file="$(find torobot_moveit_final)/launch/planning_context.launch" />`
Is included in the beginning of the launch file, which loads the robot model.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211190/ros-moveit!-move_group.launch/) by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-06-12**:
This seems to be the problem: [ERROR] [1434123343.429734522]: Robot model not loaded

**Comment by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) on 2015-06-12**:
i just edited the post, i have the include in the beginning of the launch file. It is strange, because i didn't edited the file, it was generated by MoveIt! still, isn't working.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-06-12**:
IT seems like some prefix like your robot name or something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`move_group.launch` does not load the URDF itself, it uses `planning_context.launch` for that (from `move_group.launch`):

```
<include file="$(find your_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch" />
```

But, `planning_context.launch` only loads the URDF if `load_robot_description` is `true`:

```
<param if="$(arg load_robot_description)" name="$(arg robot_description)" textfile="/path/to/your.urdf"/>
```

and by default, `load_robot_description` is `false`, so `planning_context.launch` doesn't load it.

If you look in `demo.launch`, you'll see this:

```
<!-- Load the URDF, SRDF and other .yaml configuration files on the param server -->
<include file="$(find your_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch">
  <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true" />
</include>
```

and finally:

```
<!-- Run the main MoveIt executable [..] -->
<include file="$(find your_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
  ...
</include>
```

So you'll have to set `load_robot_description` to `true` *before* you start `move_group.launch`. Whether you do that using `rosparam set ..` or by using the structure of `demo.launch` is up to you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) on 2015-06-13**:
I just edited the move_group.launch file:

```
  <include file="$(find torobot_moveit_final)/launch/planning_context.launch">
  <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true" />
  </include>
```

**Comment by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) on 2015-06-13**:
But now it gives the following error message:

```
[FATAL] [1434187128.984235619]: Parameter '~moveit_controller_manager' not specified. This is  needed to identify the plugin to use for interacting with controllers. No paths can be executed.
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-13**:
Look at what `demo.launch` does with `move_group.launch`. There is much more going on than simply setting `load_robot_description`.